# Consumir WebService da Sefaz

Tags: web-service

Preciso obter informações de uma empresa através do CNPJ, entretanto, ao pesquisar na internet pude perceber que existem diversos web-services da sefaz, cada um voltado a um estado brasileiro.

Desta forma, se o webservice é do RIO eu nao consigo recuperar informações de um CNPJ de São Paulo.

Fiquei sabendo que há um web-service 'universal' da sefaz e gostaria de encontra-lo... sabem me dizer aonde acho esse bendito? caso contrario o programa ficaria bem propenso a falhas, pois eu seria obrigado a trabalhar com um webservice para cada estado.

Comment: Amigo, eu consegui encontrar o site onde é possível fazer a pesquisa:

http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/PessoaJuridica/CNPJ/cnpjreva/Cnpjreva_Solicitacao.asp

Entretanto um webservice gratuito para fazer isto não acredito que irá encontrar, mesmo porque se pesquisar vai encontrar diversos que implementam isto e vendem o serviço.

O que ocorre é que a receita obriga digitar o captha, assim sendo o que você poderia fazer é colocar na sua aplicação para o usuario digitar o captha para poder fazer a busca.

Comment: serio? não existe uma alternativa gratuita?

Comment: Achei uma forma de faze-lo, entretanto se faz necessário o uso de um certificado de emissor de nota fiscal. Estou utilizando a propria ferramenta do C# para adicionar referencia de um serviço, e sem utilizar o certificado eu nao consigo recuperar o wsdl, gostaria de saber como inserir o bendito do certificado ao adicionar a referencia.

Comment: Infelizmente não sei como trabalhar com C#. Te recomendo criar uma nova pergunta aqui no SO

Comment: Não serviria para ti o serviço de consulta de destinatário:  https://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/NFeConsultaDest/NFeConsultaDest.asmx (para ver mais desses serviços acesse o portal da sefaz http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/webServices.aspx?tipoConteudo=Wak0FwB7dKs=)